# May F1 students with a US PhD receive their stipend if they leave the country?

Tags: phd, funding, united-states, visa, covid-19

I am considering returning to my home country since my PhD classes are being offered optionally online (which means we can take them both in person or online) for the fall semester, and the US state I currently live in has one of the worst covid-19 outbreaks. Previously, my concern was with ICE revoking my F1 status, but now that they have rescinded their proposal, this is no longer a concern for me.

My home country is in a much better situation than the US, and has free healthcare, so I wanted to return home where I am safer and with my family.

I was wondering if, under the current climate, I would be able to return home and still receive my scholarship and stipend, assuming that any TA/RA work I need to fulfill can also be done remotely?

Has anyone had an experience with this?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_visa#Travel_and_re-entry. But that is just an explanation, not a legal opinion. And, given the general hostility of the current administration, I wouldn't be sure that the rules will be maintained in their current form in any case. The stipend rules depend on whoever granted it. Check and don't assume.

Comment: At the very least you'll need to clear it with your university's international office and perhaps HR as well, since many such things depend on internal policies and interpretations as well as the law itself.  If the answer is a universal flat "no" you might be able to get such an answer on this site; but even if you find a "yes" answer, don't do anything until you have verified thoroughly that **your institution and department** will allow it.

Comment: They aren’t paying you just to go to class as a PhD student.

Comment: @JonCuster: Right, they're paying OP to work as a TA or RA, and OP expects to be able to do that work remotely.

Comment: I agree with Buffy and Nate Eldredge that you need to talk to your institution. Unless the answer is a clear "no", it likely depends on your specific forms of stipends/scholarships. As an example, Duke has a FAQ addressing their rules [here](https://gradschool.duke.edu/student-life/fall-2020-covid-19-info/fall-2020-qas-international-students-continuing-and-incoming#onlineclasses) (question 5). They state non-service stipends can continue, but clearly disallow working from abroad (and even from most states that aren't NC) - I guess for tax and/or funding reasons.

Comment: @Anyon - and question 3 there. The distinction seems to be compensatory vs non-compensatory stipend.

Comment: @JonCuster Good catch. I missed that question earlier, but it's also relevant. Agreed that Duke seems to make that distinction. I think it's a natural one, but other institutions may draw the line elsewhere.

Comment: @Anyon - yeah, I checked Princeton and they basically say stipends could be paid at the discretion of the particular program. Seems institution specific.

Comment: Hello everyone, thanks for your responses - I really appreciate it. I've contacted my department, and will see what they say.

Comment: I would just add that there have been several instances in the not so distant past in which the current administration gave serious consideration to banning re-entry even for those who had a valid visa. I don't envy your situation but if I were in the US on a visa I would be fearful of leaving if I wanted to be sure I could come back. But given the virus situation and the reasonable desire to see your family it may be rational to leave despite this (possibly small) risk as well.

Comment: @commscho could you elaborate on these 'several instances'? Anything I can read about? As far as I am aware, anyone can be denied at the port of entry, visa-holder or not, but you are talking about the current administration talking about banning re-entry altogether? I will specify that I am an Australian citizen, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Please do not take advice from random strangers on the internet for this matter.  Get it in writing from your institution's administrators.

Comment: I'd assume any travel at this time could be one-way for the foreseeable future.